# How to start my app from browser as a separated task

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

My activity definition looks like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.broadvision.myvv.MyVV_Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />  
            <data android:scheme="vmoso" /> 
            <data 
                android:host="www.vmoso.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This activity is root activity in my app, it can be started from browser app, after this, if I hit browser icon, what I want to see is the browser UI, but in fact, I still see my own app, which is incorrect. 
I've tried to add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, it works for this case, i.e.: my app activity starts as a new task, and I can switch back to browser, but when I hit my app icon from home screen, it always starts as a new task, which is not what I want to see, I want to see the last Activity when I leave. 
Also tried `android:allowTaskReparenting="true"`, but doesn't work, I believe the point is on `launchMode`, but after tried all 4 modes, still cannot figure it out.

Comment: you define the scheme twice, you just need it  inside  the second <data>. Did you try by using your own scheme?

Comment: I try from browser by using the second <data>, i.e.: the http scheme. I'll move the 1st scheme into the 2nd <data>.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question earlier.  I think you just need to put android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" as an attribute of <activity>

Comment: @Jibbo I tried to add `android:clearTaskOnLaunch=true`, but get the same result, my app still stays in the task of browser app.

Comment: try defining a different process in <activity> if it still doesn't work than all I have is an hacky way :S

Comment: Sorry, here's the link on how to do it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc

Comment: Added `android:process="@string/app_name"`, sorry it doesn't work. BTW, when I did my testings, I have no `launchMode` attribute set, and I think I need it. But if I add it, I will run into another issue as I descriped.

Comment: The only launchmode that i can think of in this segment is "singleTop".. but if you still have that issue there's only the way of an activity that just launch your other activity with the CLEAR_TOP and NEW_TASK flags but it's hacky....

Comment: `NEW_TASK` should be the same as `singleTask` defined in manifest. And I am starting my app from Android built-in browser app (and it is also possible from other apps), I cannot modifed their code to add any flag to intent when starting my activity.

Comment: I didin't express myself well, what I meant was something like this: browser->click->open an "invisible" activity which calls your other activity with the above mentioned parameters->your app will start in a different session than the browser's and it will recover from when you left if you close it.